# Docusign Custom Button on Lead - Lead not linking to Recipient Status object

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I've created a custom button on our Lead object in Salesforce which works perfectly except for the Lead record where is not linking to the Recipient Status record so I'm unable to see docusign status on the associated records.  Am I missing something in my button setup?

Here is the code for the button:

```
var DST=''; 
var LA='0'; 
var CRCL ='Lead__r,Email~Email;FirstName~FirstName;LastName~LastName'; 
var CES='{!Lead.FirstName}, You have a document to sign for Dharma Merchant Services'; 
var CRL = 'Role~Signer 1;Email~{!Lead.Signer_Email__c};FirstName~{!Lead.Signer_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Lead.Signer_Last_Name__c},Role~Signer 2;Email~{!Lead.X2nd_Signer_Email__c};FirstName~{!Lead.X2nd_Signer_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Lead.X2nd_Signer_Last_Name__c}'; 

var processor = '{!Lead.Processor__c}'; 
if(processor=='Priority Payments'){ 
DST = '58D882D3-088F-42B4-82C5-E88D899163D9'; 
}else if(processor=='Select Bankcard') { 
DST = '75E8C817-AEDF-4138-9F7A-8132E8389425'; 
} 
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Lead.Id}&DST="+DST+"&LA="+LA+"&CRL="+CRL+"&CES="+CES+"&CRCL="+CRCL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your issue but, if it's simply a matter of DocuSign Envelope or Recipient Status not being updated/reflected within related objects in SFDC, then it's most likely that your DocuSign Connect settings aren't configured properly.If you haven't done so already, I'd recommend reviewing the [DocuSign Connect for Salesforce guide](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20Connect%20for%20Salesforce.pdf) for information about how to configure Connect such that DocuSign pushes status back into SFDC in the scenarios you specify.

Answer (score 0):

I just got off the phone with Docusign and this is a known bug with Custom Buttons.  When using custom buttons on the Lead the Recipient Status is not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an enhancement to the managed package. Please reference the below workaround:

[DocuSign for Salesforce: Reference Lead Record to Recipient Status When Creating Envelopes From Custom Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414897/docusign-for-salesforce-reference-lead-record-to-recipient-status-when-creating/25416714#25416714)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, leads are not linked to envelopes by default:

DocuSign Connect Settings > DocuSign Connect for Salesforce > Edit dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c >
in the update fields section add Lead(reference) as salesforce fields and select Recipient External Lead as the Docusign field

then under envelope publish select the timeframe, generate, select the envelopes and publish the xml