# DocuSign for Salesforce: Reference Lead Record to Recipient Status When Creating Envelopes From Custom Button

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have written custom button logic for my Leads object to pull in the Lead Contact info. Example script below:

```
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';var CRL='';

CCRM ='Executive Sponsor~Signer 1';

CCTM='Executive Sponsor~Signer';

CRL='Email~{!Lead.Email};FirstName~{!URLENCODE(Lead.FirstName)};LastName~{!URLENCODE(Lead.LastName)};Role~Executive Sponsor';


window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Lead.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES+"&CRL="+CRL;
```

This currently works on pulling the recipient into the envelope, but does not relate the Recipient Status to the correct Lead record.

Answer (score 5):

In order to reference the Lead to my RecipientStatus, I had to remove all the parameters from my original logic:

```
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';var CRL='';



window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Lead.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES+"&CRL="+CRL;
```

The above option is useful if you're not using templates and need to define other parameters in your button logic.

If defining the template role is crucial to your workflow, I found an option to manipulate DocuSign Connect. My Connect workflow searches for the DocuSign Recipient Name and updates the Lead reference lookup field for *DocuSign Recipient Status*.

Example Below:[image]

It is also very important to run this Connect workflow after DocuSign Recipient Status. You cannot update a record that has not exist yet:
[image]